# iOS latin localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

[In summary here.](http://thejoysofcode.com/post/35197031533/when-i-try-to-manage-the-coding-of-special-characters)

We have a medical app that includes a latin locale. On the latest Xcode, I can't add it as a localization for the project. Bug? Not possible? How can we have latin as a locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS does not list Latin as an available language (General > International > Language), so even if you were able to add Latin localizations in your XCode project, it wouldn't be possible to use it. Unless you intend to provide your own in-app language switch?

By the way, not to be pedantic but Latin is not a locale, it's a language.

Comment: Yes it is basically an in app language switch. The content can be displayed in latin but we were hoping we could use use the system settings. As you say, it seems we can't.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the project file in the project navigator.

Then select the project file.

There you will get option to add languages that you need to support.

Hope this helps.